# Mulesoft build failure on CI / CD server (bamboo / artifactory) that succeeds locally

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

Mulesoft build gives a `'LifecycleException: failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start"' on DefaultHttpListenerConfig with a 'BindException address already in use'` only on our CI / CD server.

The corresponding build and munits succeed locally, but as soon as svn triggers a bamboo / artifactory build on the build server the errors (below) occur even before munits are run (`'Tests: 0'`), so it seems to be on pre-invocation of tests.

There is no HTTP listener that I have defined called `DefaultHttpListenerConfig` and I changed all ports in mule-app.properties to localhost (even as munits were mocking all HTTP endpoints).

Build failure messages:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListenerConfig@2f07930a
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.munit.runner.simple.MunitSimpleRunner.run(MunitSimpleRunner.java:54)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.munit.remote.path.ApplicationPathBuilder.buildApplicationPaths(ApplicationPathBuilder.java:80)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.munit.remote.path.ApplicationPathBuilder.getFlowPaths(ApplicationPathBuilder.java:41)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.munit.remote.CoverageManager.generateCoverageReport(CoverageManager.java:82)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.calculateCoverageIfApplicable(RemoteRunner.java:119)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.run(RemoteRunner.java:65)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.main(RemoteRunner.java:39)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06    Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListenerConfig@2f07930a
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:249)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:99)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:71)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:311)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.startMule(MuleContextManager.java:77)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.startMule(MuleContextManager.java:71)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at org.mule.munit.runner.simple.MunitSimpleRunner.run(MunitSimpleRunner.java:47)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        ... 6 more
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
build    28-Mar-2017 12:11:06        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)a
```

Comment: (See below for solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is thrown because your mule test configuration is using a port that is already used on your bamboo server.
Can you run this command on your bamboo server? Replace of course 80 with the port that your tests are using

```
sudo netstat -plnt | grep ':80'
```

If you get the command prompt response is something like this:

```
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      8448/httpd
```

It means the port is already taken in which case you should use another port for your test configuration.

Comment: When you say 'the port that your tests are using' do you mean the actual ports that i have set up for *my* http connectors (8085, 8087, 443) which are all being mocked, or the port used by munit *itself* (6661 in debug configurations)?

The CI/CD server is running win server 2012, so  'netstat -plnt' is not available, but basic 'netstat' doesn't seem to be showing any of the ports i'm interested in.

Comment: Fixed!

'netstat -a -n -p tcp' (on Win) shows me that certain ports (8081, 8085, 443) were being used for localhost, so I changed all my HTTP listeners to different ports (including 1443 instead of 443 for HTTPS / TLS) _even tho_ they were all being mocked (and none were named 'DefaultHttpListenerConfig') and that seems to have cleared the problem.

Would have been nice if the bind exception had named the address / port it was failing on....

Comment: That's what I was talking about! I'm glad you fixed it!